# Pipewire: multichannel audio using two devices

Tags: linux, audio, pipewire

I am running a fully-updated Manjaro linux. Until recently, I had 2 Fireface 800's, which are firewire, and I used jack and ffado, which combined the two 8-channel devices into a single virtual 16-channel device that was usable from portaudio. Drift isn't an issue as I sync via wordclock.

As an upgrade, I bought two RME Fireface UFX + cards, each also having 8 analog channels. I'd also like to switch to pipewire, but with the same setup: a single 16-channel virtual device. For testing, I am on another machine with a built-in sound chip, and a usb soundcard attached, and I assume that a working configuration here will translate well to the machine with the RME's. I am trying to configure pipewire to do what I want, I think I am close but it isn't working quite correctly. Here is what I have done:

I first copied the pipewire conf file:

```
mkdir ~/.config/pipewire
cp /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire.conf ~/.config/pipewire
```

I then edited the config file and added the following codeblock inside context.modules:

```
{   name = libpipewire-module-combine-stream
    args = {
        combine.mode = sink
        node.name = "4_channel_output"
        node.description = "4-channel Output"
        combine.props = {
            audio.position = [ FL FR SL SR ]
        }
        stream.props = {
                stream.dont-remix = true
        }
        stream.rules = [
            {   matches = [
                    {   media.class = "Stream/Output/Audio" #"Audio/Source"
                        node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo"
                    } ]
                actions = { create-stream = {
                        audio.position = [ playback_FL playback_FR ]
                        combine.audio.position = [ FL FR ]
                } } }
            {   matches = [
                    {   media.class = "Stream/Output/Audio" #"Audio/Source"
                        node.name = "alsa_output.usb-TEAC_TEAC_USB_AUDIO_DEVICE-02.analog-stereo"
                    } ]
                actions = { create-stream = {
                        audio.position = [ playback_FL playback_FR ]
                        combine.audio.position = [ SL SR ]
                } } }
        ]
    }
}
```

And I restart pipewire:

```
systemctl --user restart pipewire.service
```

This is close. When I choose the pipewire device in portaudio, I can play sound out to 4 channels. But I only hear sound out of the usb (TEAC) device. pa_out_ch1 -> usb_ch1; pa_out_ch2 -> usb_ch2; pa_out_ch3 -> usb_ch1; pa_out_ch4 -> usb_ch2. I get no sound out of the onboard chip.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am using multiple different USB interfaces with Manjaro KDE, and pipewire. I realize this is quite different from your setup. However, I think you may have luck - as I have - by installing pavucontrol or pavucontrol-qt (if KDE). Then set you interfaces to 'Pro Audio' from the pavucontrol application.

My RodeCaster II Pro only showed 2 channels in qpwgraph, etc. without doing this. With pavucontrol set to Pro Audio I get all 16 inputs and all 6 outputs. They are all fully functional.

Same initial issue and full resolution on my Audient EVO8.